# How restart a closed video track , stopped using userStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop()

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, webrtc

I am trying to implement, the video on/off toggle for a webRtc application in react, so far i am able to stop the video using

**`userStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop()`**

but can't seem to find any function to restart the video track .

I have tried the `.enable` method

```
 userStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = !userStream.getVideoTracks()[0]
```

but using this still leaves the webcam light on, which in undesirable but gets the functionality working,
on the other hand   `userStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop()` turns off the light but i am not able start it back. 
Is there anyway to achive this without creating a new stream.

Answer (score 2):

When you use track.stop() you can't reuse the track. You'll have to create a new one.

With the track.enabled method it should normally get the functionality that you're looking for. Disabling the camera indicator when disabled. Because as the official docs state:

> If the MediaStreamTrack represents the video input from a camera, disabling the track by setting enabled to false also updates device activity indicators to show that the camera is not currently recording or streaming. For example, the green "in use" light next to the camera in iMac and MacBook computers turns off while the track is muted in this way.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/enabled

It could be another track is still using your track or it could be something browser version related why your camera indicator is still on.

Comment: I am using Version 84.0.4147.135  of chrome , so i think the issue is not related to  browser version , i also checked i am not using the track anywhere else , also I tried this in firefox,  same results , setting .enabled doesn't turn of my web cam light, check this link https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/web_camera_light ,  i think my only option is to create another track. If there is a better way to do this , please do tell  . basically i want to share webcam video , audio , screen through webRTC  and want to toggle these on and off. Would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: What I do is just recreate a new stream also. You can create a function for every stream type that creates a new stream if it's tracks stopped or just returns the stored stream. It's not so hard to implement

Comment: I suppose the enabled flag isn't implemented correctly in the browsers. Or the official docs must be changed.

Answer (score 1):

best way to do is you can replace tracks.

```
function replaceTracks(elementId, newStream, localStream, peerConnection) {

    detachMediaStream(elementId);

    newStream.getTracks().forEach(function (track) {
      localStream.addTrack(track);
    });

    attachMediaStream(elementId, newStream);

    // optionally, if you have active peer connections:
    _replaceTracksForPeer(peerConnection);

    function _replaceTracksForPeer(peer) {
      console.log(peer)
      peer.getSenders().map(function (sender) {
        sender.replaceTrack(newStream.getTracks().find(function (track) {
          return track.kind === sender.track.kind;
        }));
      });
    }
    function attachMediaStream(id, stream) {
      var elem: any = document.getElementById(id);

      if (elem) {
        if (typeof elem.srcObject === 'object') {
          elem.srcObject = stream;
        } else {
          elem.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        }

        elem.onloadedmetadata = function (e) {
          elem.play();
        };
      } else {
        throw new Error('Unable to attach media stream');
      }
    }
    function detachMediaStream(id) {
      var elem;
      elem = document.getElementById(id);

      if (elem) {
        elem.pause();

        if (typeof elem.srcObject === 'object') {
          elem.srcObject = null;
        } else {
          elem.src = '';
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: its good idea but need to be less detailed